# Use two custom validation functions with different updateOn options on one form control

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-reactive-forms

I want to use two custom validation functions with two updateOn options (blur and change). The scenario is when changing passwords, new pass should be validated against the password policies with updateOn: 'change' which is default and also should be validated against the current password on updateOn: 'blur' option.

```
newPassword: new FormControl('', { validators: [Validators.required, passwordMatch()], asyncValidators: [validatePassword()], updateOn: 'blur' }),
```

I want to validate password with updateOn: 'blur' for passwordMatch() and  validatePassword() with updateOn: 'change' for the same form control

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, but you can add an asyncValidator in submit. After updateValueAndValidity, subscribe to statusChange, and in this subscription check if is valid for submit or not the form

```
  status:any; //<--it's necesary create a variable

  submit() {
    //add the asyncValidator
    this.newPassword.setAsyncValidators(this.validateAsync())

    //call to updateValueAndValidity
    this.newPassword.updateValueAndValidity();

    //store in a variable the status
    this.status=this.newPassword.status

    this.newPassword.statusChanges.pipe(
      takeWhile(()=>this.status=='PENDING')  //<--use takeWhile to unsubscribe
    ).subscribe((status) => {
        this.newPassword.clearAsyncValidators();
        this.status=this.newPassword.status
        if (this.newPassword.valid) //<--check if is valid or not  
          alert('submit')
      })
  }
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cstdc6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)